# Triggers: Update table2 with info from table1

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, triggers

Using SSMS 2008.

I have 2 tables:

```
TABLE1:
PKField (Primary Key)
Field2
Field3

TABLE2:
PKField (Primary Key)
FKField (Foreign Key to Table1.PKField)
Field2
Field3
```

I need to create a trigger on TABLE2 that does this:

Whenever rows are INSERTED into TABLE2 (Field2 and Field3 will always be null at this point) then UPDATE the fields TABLE2.Field2 and TABLE2.Field3 *based on* TABLE1.Field2 and TABLE2.Field3 values.

Using SSMS 2008 how do I do this? I'm new to triggers, etc...

Thanks!

Comment: Seems to me that copying the data from table1 to table2 is a bad design. You should keep that data properly normalized and in table1. What happens when table1 is updated? Do you also have to then update table2?

Comment: Generally, the best way to write a trigger is not to write such. Could you reconsider using triggers? If not, look for `INSTEAD OF INSERT` trigger.

Comment: @SeanLange I'm working on an inherited, pre-existing, hugely complex, app. I realize what you're saying. But, in this case, it has to be done this way unfortunately. (I don't have to worry about when table1 is updated... in this case.)

Comment: @gotqn Thanks. Not sure what you mean but I will look into it.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a rough sketch based on your example tables.

```
create trigger MyTrigger on Tabel2 INSTEAD OF INSERT AS
    Insert Table2 (PKField, FKField, Field2, Field3)
    select i.PKField
        , i.FKField
        , t.Field2
        , t.Field3
    from Inserted i
    join Table1 t on t.PKField = i.FKField
```

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189799.aspx) you can find more information triggers. I recommend to you to read it first before start doing anything.

In your case, I believe you should create `INSTEAD OF INSERT` trigger:

> INSTEAD OF
>
> Specifies that the DML trigger is executed instead of the triggering SQL statement,
>   therefore, overriding the actions of the triggering statements.
>   INSTEAD OF cannot be specified for DDL or logon triggers. At most, one
>   INSTEAD OF trigger per INSERT, UPDATE, or DELETE statement can be
>   defined on a table or view.

For example:

```
--Create an INSTEAD OF INSERT trigger on the view.
CREATE TRIGGER myTrigger on myTable
INSTEAD OF INSERT
AS
BEGIN
  -- do whatever you want here
  -- the code is executed when an insertion is made on the underlying table
END;
GO
```

You can find more information about `INSTEAD OF INSERT` trigger [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175089(v=sql.105).aspx).

I guess the only question you will have is how to refer the data that is initially inserted in the underlying table?

The answer is using the `inserted` table - [read more about it](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191300.aspx)